# Express Problem routes ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initializationproblem auth

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a route that updates a password and then I want to `console.log` the user found with the updated result but I got an error.

Error:

```js
(node:13892) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: `findOneAndUpdate()` and `findOneAndDelete()` without the `useFindAndModify` option set to false are deprecated. See: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'user' before initializationproblem auth
```

Code:

```js
router.get(
  "/superuser/resendWelcomeMail",
  (req, res) => {
    console.log("inFunction");
    let passwordRaw = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
    let password = passwordRaw;
        let user = await User.findOneAndModify(
          {
            email: req.query.email,
          },
          {
            password: password,
          }
        )
          .then(() => {
            console.log(user);
            );
            res.redirect("/superuser/businesses");
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err + "problem auth"));
      });
    });
  }
);
```

I still don't understand if the error comes from the function `findOneAndUpdate` or from this await function and the then `.then()`

I would be happy to get some insights or help.

Answer (score 1):

It comes from the `then()` callback function, where you're trying to read the value of the `user` variable before it has been initialized - ie assigned a value as part of its declaration. You can not do that with `let` bindings.

Here, the assignment to `user` will not happen until the whole promise chain unwraps - which will occur only when either the `then()` or `catch()` callback function returns.

You should just stick to the `await` syntax and write the whole code in synchronous style - rather than mixing in `then()/catch()` callbacks -, and the problem should take care of itself.

```
try {
  let user = await User.findOneAndModify(
    { email: req.query.email },
    { password: password }
  )

  console.log(user);
  res.redirect("/superuser/businesses");
} catch(error) {
  console.log(err + "problem auth"));
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's sounds right, I will check it tomorrow and validate the Res.